# how to localize iOS 8 today extensions widget and also the widget name

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I can't understand how I can localize today extensions, I want to create the `Localize.strings` file like a normal `xcode` project that for example have this string:

```
.en
    "Apple" = "Apple"

.it
    "Apple" = "Mela"
```

and I also want to know how I can localize the iOS 8 Today Extensions widget name.

I have tried to create a `Strings File` in Xcode, and I have tried to insert this:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name";
```

but the name doesn't change...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName = YES` to `Info.plist` file and add your localizations to `InfoPlist.strings` which you have to place under the `language.proj` folder per languages, for example `de.lproj` for German versions.

Before testing:
- Clean the project
- Remove the application from the simulator.
- Add `language.proj` folder references to extension's `Supporting files` part - to include them inside `Copy bundle resources` section in `Build Phases` of your extension target.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and where i have to insert the localized name?

Comment: thanks, and the file InfoPlist.strings where is? i have to create it?

Comment: jp.lproj, fr.lproj, it.lproj ... folders

Comment: Remove the application from simulator and clean the project before trying.

Comment: i have do all, now the name of the widget change, but the NSLocalizedString(@"Apple", @"") for example doesn't change, in the InfoPlist.strings i have add this: "Apple" = "Apple" in the .en and this for example "Apple" = "Mela" in the .it but only the CFBundleDisplayName works...any suggestion?

Comment: `InfoPlist.strings` file is only for values in `Info.plist`. Try Localizable.strings for others

Answer (score 2):

For strings in your containing app and `Today Widget` can share the same localization files. You can simply select **Localizable.string**, and in the **`File inspector`** check your today widget target in `Target Membership`. Then all your `NSLocalizedString` in the today widget share the same one with the containing localization strings.

For the today widget application name, then just add an `InfoPlist.strings` file, and

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Translated Name";
"CFBundleName" = "Translated Name";
```

Just run your containing app for testing.